# Pandas Get Dummy Reversal For Prediction

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I have a dataframe that looks like this called Dataframe 1

```
year  month  day  feature_x feature_y
2020  5      1    3         2
2020  5      1    1         3
2020  5      1    2         1
```

Then I applied `pd.get_dummies()` and it looks like Dataframe 2

```
year  month  day  feature_x_1  feature_x_2  feature_x_3  feature_y_1  feature_y_2.  feature_y_3
2020  5      1    0            0            1            0            1             0
2020  5      1    1            0            0            0            1             0
2020  5      1    0            1            0            0            1             0
```

Now I have a prediction Dataframe 3 that look like the first one, but only 1 row. It looks like this

```
year  month  day  feature_x feature_y
2020  2      10   1         3
```

Desired output should look like Dataframe 2 which looks like this

```
year  month  day  feature_x_1  feature_x_2  feature_x_3  feature_y_1  feature_y_2.  feature_y_3
2020  2      10   1            0            0            0            0             1
```

Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `reindex` to have the result dataframe have same columns as the second one:

```
Dataframe4 = pd.get_dummies(Dataframe3, columns=['feature_x', 'feature_y']
               ).reindex(columns=Dataframe2.columns).fillna(0).astype('int')
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following:

```
# initialize the provided data frames
Dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame([[2020, 5, 1, 3, 2],
                           [2020, 5, 1, 1, 3],
                           [2020, 5, 1, 2, 1]] ,
                          columns = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'feature_x', 'feature_y'])

Dataframe2 = pd.get_dummies(Dataframe1, columns = ['feature_x', 'feature_y'])

Dataframe3 = pd.DataFrame([[2020, 2, 10, 1, 3]] ,
                          columns = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'feature_x', 'feature_y'])

# a dictionary of each feature for which dummies are desired
features_to_dummies = {'feature_x' : [], 'feature_y' : []}

# add the corresponding dummies as values to the dictionary
for feature in features_to_dummies.keys():
    for column_name in Dataframe2.columns.values:
        if feature in column_name:
            features_to_dummies[feature].append(column_name)

# add the same dummy variables to Dataframe3, all initialized to 0
for feature in features_to_dummies.keys():
    for dummy in features_to_dummies[feature]:
        Dataframe3[dummy] = 0

# set the dummy variables to the proper value
for feature in features_to_dummies.keys():
    Dataframe3[feature + '_' + str(Dataframe3.iloc[0][feature])] = 1

# drop the initial features
Dataframe3.drop(columns = features_to_dummies.keys(), inplace = True)
```

This yields the desired output:

```
        year    month   day feature_x_1 feature_x_2 feature_x_3 feature_y_1 feature_y_2 feature_y_3
0       2020    2       10  1           0           0           0           0           1
```

Note that the features which should be converted to dummies need to be hardcoded (added to the 'features_to_dummies' dictionary in the form 'feature_name' : []) with this approach.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import pandas as pd
Dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame([[2020, 5, 1, 3, 2],
                           [2020, 5, 1, 1, 3],
                           [2020, 5, 1, 2, 1]] ,
                          columns = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'feature_x', 'feature_y'])

Dataframe2 = pd.get_dummies(Dataframe1, columns = ['feature_x', 'feature_y'])

Dataframe3 = pd.DataFrame([[2020, 2, 10, 1, 3]] ,
                          columns = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'feature_x', 'feature_y'])


Dataframe4 = pd.get_dummies(Dataframe3, columns = ['feature_x', 'feature_y'])
misscols = list(set(Dataframe2.columns) - set(Dataframe4.columns))
for col in misscols:
    Dataframe4[col] = 0
Dataframe4 = Dataframe4[Dataframe2.columns]
```